# Как запретить удалять в инпуте первый символ?

Tags: javascript, jquery

допустим по умолчанию value="+"
суть - запретить его удалять

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаю путь намного проще, чем писать скрипт "запрещения удаления":

Просто перед инпутом стоИт какой-нибудь `span`, в котором этот плюс нарисован. В итоге пользователь спокойно вводит номер, да и вам проще на сервере получать что-то без всяких плюсов спереди